# regex date extract month. dd, yyyy or mmm dd, yyyy or month dd, yyyy

Tags: regex, date, extract

text = 'This is my text I will search through for patterns September. 21, 2012. As well as July 25, 1998 and a date like Oct 18, 1980'

I need to extract a date like "September. 21, 2012" or "July 25, 1998" or "Oct 18, 1980" and I struggle to find the right regular expression(s) for that.

Can someone provide some help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @meta welcome 2 SO. Can you pls show your attempts?

Answer (score 1):

This works for your example (Note: using python re regex flavour since not specified):

```
[A-Z][a-z]*(\. | )[0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4}
```

Explanation:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*  # Capitalised word

(\. | )      # Followed by a literal fullstop or a space

[0-9]{2}     # Two digits

,            # Comma and space

[0-9]{4}     # Four digits
```

Test out your regexes here: https://regex101.com/